# Solve a coupled ODE system $x'(t)$ and $y'(t)$ including time $t$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I met this ODE system of functions $x(t), y(t)$, with initial values $x(0)=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}, y(0)=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$.
\begin{equation}
\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{d}t}=-y+x(x^2+y^2)\sin\frac{\pi}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}t}=x+y(x^2+y^2)\sin\frac{\pi}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}
\end{equation}
I tried to eliminate the second term including function $\sin$
\begin{equation}
\frac{\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{d}t}+y}{\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}t}-x}=\frac{x}{y}
\end{equation}
After substituting $\frac{x}{y}$ with $u$, the above equation becomes
\begin{equation}
\mathrm{d}u=-(1+u^2)\Rightarrow \arctan u=-u+C
\end{equation}
Use initial values, $\arctan 1=-1+C$ meaning $C=\frac{\pi}{4}+1$. But it seems more difficult when I tried to substitute $u$ back to the ODE system. Can we have a better solution?

Comment: Use polar coordinates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We try to decouple the system with transformation

$$x(t)=r(t) \cos (\phi (t)),\quad y(t)=r(t) \sin (\phi (t))$$

Hence we get

$$r'(t) \cos (\phi (t))-r(t) \left(\phi '(t)-1\right) \sin (\phi (t))+r(t)^3 \sin \left(\frac{\pi }{\sqrt{r(t)^2}}\right) (-\cos (\phi (t)))=0$$

$$r'(t) \sin (\phi (t))+r(t) \left(\phi '(t)-1\right) \cos (\phi (t))+r(t)^3 \sin \left(\frac{\pi }{\sqrt{r(t)^2}}\right) \sin (\phi (t))=0$$

Isolating $r'(t), \phi'(t)$ yields

$$r'(t)= r(t)^3 \sin \left(\frac{\pi }{\sqrt{r(t)^2}}\right)$$
$$\phi '(t)= 1$$

Integrating the 2 equations we get the implicit solution

$$\int \frac{\csc \left(\frac{\pi }{| r| }\right)}{r^3} \, dr=t+c_1$$

$$\phi (t)= t+c_2$$

We are also able to evaluate the integral:

$$\int \frac{\csc \left(\frac{\pi }{| r| }\right)}{r^3} \, dr=-\frac{i \left(\text{Li}_2\left(-e^{\frac{i \pi }{r}}\right)-\text{Li}_2\left(e^{\frac{i \pi }{r}}\right)\right)+\frac{\pi  \left(\log \left(1-e^{\frac{i \pi }{r}}\right)-\log \left(1+e^{\frac{i \pi }{r}}\right)\right)}{r}}{\pi ^2}\qquad r\in \mathbb{R}\land r>0$$

with $\text{Li}_{n}(z)$ the polylogarithm function.

Solutions of $r(t)$ depending on $r(0)$:

[image]

Comment: Yes, I did the problem like this, but you see, it's really horrible to calculate the function $r(t)$...